# /tmp/mysql.sock disappears after stopping mysql - can't restart on OSX

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-mavericks

I am trying to get mysql set up properly on OSX Mavericks. I have installed the 3 packages from here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/. Everything works as expected.

However, when I click *Stop MySQL Server* in the preferences pain window shown below, I cannot restart the server. I am pretty sure that this is due to the fact that the `/tmp/mysql.sock` file gets removed. The only way to get the server to start again is to restart my computer, which is less than ideal.

[image]

How can I get the /tmp/mysql.sock file to stick around even after stopping the server?

As a side note I have symlinked the mysql.sock file using this command, but I don't think this is related

```
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I also noticed that I cannot find a my.cnf file anywhere. Should I create this file someplace?

Comment: @floww it is only deleted after the server is stopped. I have tried to restart from the command line. The only thing that works is to restart the machine.

Comment: @DigitalChris that makes sense - it seems like maybe my machine just can't create the file on service start, maybe? Not sure how this is not my problem tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing all files using this post as a reference http://akrabat.com/computing/uninstalling-mysql-on-mac-os-x-leopard/ and reinstalling using homebrew `brew install mysql`. So far so good with this install. Probably was some kind of permission issue preventing mysql.sock from being created on start - but not too sure.